# Accessing values from Alfresco's alfresco-global.properties file

Tags: alfresco

Lets say I create a custom property called "test123" inside of the alfresco-global.properties file. Is there a custom object or some other way which I can use to access its value inside of a Java bean in Alfresco?

Comment: Are you looking to inject the values into your own bean (which is the way that those properties are normally used), or are you hoping to dynamically look up random properties at runtime?

Comment: Either would work, though probably the former. I'm not too worried about the config values after Alfresco has started up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Spring bean is called "global-properties" and it's a java.util.Properties type

So you can inject it like that:

```
<property name="properties">
  <ref bean="global-properties"/>
</property
```

and add a properties property of type java.util.Properties to your bean

Comment: How can you do to link the property added in java class to the name "properties" ?

Comment: Perfectly worked for me. And the JAVA part is 

[

private Properties properties;

properties.getProperty("your key from alfresco-global.properties");

]

Comment: Can we set/override properties runtime using this way?

Answer (score 8):

All properties from the *alfresco-global.properties* are available as placeholders in the Spring bean definition. You can simply use:

```
<property name="myCustomOption" value="${my.custom.option}"/>
```

in your bean definition and in alfresco-global.properties:

```
my.custom.option=Some string value
```

Injecting the whole *global-properties* bean (as proposed above) also works but violates the [principle of least knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: It is also possibile to use annotation `@Value("${my.custom.option}")` in Java bean class.

Comment: You are right, back in 2014 only XML configuration was used for Alfresco.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, see last snippet within [this post](http://www.shmoula.cz/custom-configs-in-alfresco/).