# accessing alfresco-global.properties from FTL

Tags: properties, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have defined a property in "**alfresco-global.properties**". How can I access this property from the **FTL** file of my webscript in Alfresco **Share**?

I'm using Alfresco Community Version 4.2

Comment: You're going to need to write a bit of Java code, sorry. It's basically the same process as accessing it from JavaScript

Comment: I don't think this is possible, not with just writing some lines in that very ftl you want it. btw -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366978/how-to-access-values-from-alfresco-global-properties-in-freemarker-and-yui-javas

Comment: We've written a module with can access these fields in JavaScript, then you can pass the value to the Freemarker ftl file. Send me an email and i'll provide you the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access properties files directly from the view **(FTL)**, it violates the [Separation Of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.

Since the **alfresco-global-properties** is actually a spring bean of type `java.util.Properties`, you can inject the whole thing into your Java Class of your webscript:

```
<property name="properties">
    <ref bean="global-properties"/>
</property>
```

And then you can access your property like this `properties.getProperty("my.custom.property")`