# Dynamic access to alfresco-global.properties

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, spring-annotations

I can't access to alfresco-global.properties values dynamically although I read this post: 
[Accessing values from Alfresco's alfresco-global.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452800/accessing-values-from-alfrescos-alfresco-global-properties-file)

Here is my conf:

service-context.xml

```
<bean id="AccesGlobalPropertiesService" class="com.package.ksc.services.AccesGlobalPropertiesService">
     <property name="properties">
        <ref bean="global-properties"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

AccesGlobalPropertiesService.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.Properties;

@Service
public class AccesGlobalPropertiesService {

    public Properties properties;

    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Worker.java

```
public abstract class ClassifierServiceCommon {

   private AccesGlobalProperties accesGlobalProperties;
   private Properties properties;    

   /* Constructor */
   protected Worker(accesGlobalProperties) {
     this.accesGlobalProperties= accesGlobalProperties;
   }

   ...

   protected Boolean propAcces() {
      accesGlobalProperties.properties.getProperty("myPropKey");
      ...
   }
}
```

I get a NullPointerException when I call getProperty("myPropKey") ...

What's wrong please?
Thanks

Comment: have you inject AccesGlobalProperties properly? can you add snippet of your context file

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you made the mistake of defining two beans with different ID-s:

1. One bean comes from the XML, its ID is explicitly specified as "AccesGlobalPropertiesService". Its `properties` field is correctly set.
2. The other bean comes from Spring component scanning (thanks to the `@Service` annotation), its ID is implicitly set to "accesGlobalPropertiesService". Its `properties` field is not set, because a `@Resource` or `@Autowired` annotation is missing for that field (see e. g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired) on how to use them).

And then you most probably use the second (incomplete) one from your `ClassifierServiceCommon` class. (You didn't specify how you get the bean there.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the variable (You don't seem to do it). You need to setProperty() before you getProperty(). As long as you don't initialize properties in the AccesGlobalPropertiesService class, your getProperty() will return null.

I don't know if that's what you're trying to do here :

```
protected Boolean propAcces(){

  accesGlobalProperties.properties.getProperty("myPropKey");
  ...
}
```

If that is the case, you should change getProperty for setProperty.

I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link for details.

https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/reading-properties-file-through-java-backend-webscript/m-p/148000